# HTML5 Stress Testing

Tags: html, stress-testing, android-browser

We have a webapp that's backed by a java spring web application.  Apparently our Rational Robot tool that we normally would use to stress test a browser application doesn't deal with the HTML5'ness of our app.  We are considering simply scripting the raw http requests to beat on the application, but wondering if anyone knows of any tools out there to do the same without having to craft all of the http requests by hand?

Answer (score 1):

[Apache JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) allows you to record all http requests by setting it up as a proxy. You can then save those requests and play them back in multiple threads to simulate users.

Comment: I highly recommend JMeter for beating up the server.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler with our free stress testing add-on called [StresStimulus](http://stresstimulus.stimulustechnology.com/) is another proxy that records HTTP requests and replays them with configurable user ramping.

Answer (score 0):

If you have anything a bit complex, it would be easier to record a script in one of the load testing tools. I have used [WebLOAD](http://www.radview.com) in the past, which handles things like fetching all the sub-components, script correlation, AJAX recording, etc.

You can record straight from the Android device, or use a desktop browser you like.